# NSubstitute Test against classes (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

First of all I'm a beginner in unit tests. For my tests i want to use NSubstitute, so I read the tutorial on the website and also the mock comparison from Richard Banks. Both of them are testing against interfaces, not against classes. The statement is "Generally this [substituted] type will be an interface, but you can also substitute classes in cases of **emergency**."

Now I'm wondering about the purpose of testing against interfaces. Here is the example interface from the NSubstitute website (please note, that i have converted the C#-code in VB.net):

```
Public Interface ICalculator
    Function Add(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
    Property Mode As String
    Event PoweringUp As EventHandler
End Interface
```

And here is the unit test from the website (under the NUnit-Framework):

```
<Test>
Sub ReturnValue_For_Methods()

    Dim calculator = Substitute.For(Of ICalculator)()
    calculator.Add(1, 2).Returns(3)

    Assert.AreEqual(calculator.Add(1, 2), 3)

End Sub
```

Ok, that works and the unit test will perform successful. But what sense makes this? This do not test any code. The *Add*-Method could have any errors, which will not be detected when testing against interfaces - like this:

```
Public Class Calculator
    Implements ICalculator

    Public Function Add(a As Double, b As Double) As Double Implements ICalculator.Add
        Return 1 / 0
    End Function

    ...

End Class
```

The *Add*-Method performs a division by zero, so the unit test should fail - but because of testing against the interface ICalculator the test is successful.

Could you please help me to understand that? What sense makes it, not to test the code but the interface?

Thanks in advance
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind mocking is to isolate a class we are testing from its dependencies. So we don't mock the class we are testing, in this case `Calculator`, we mock an `ICalculator` when testing a class that uses an `ICalculator`.

A small example is when we want to test how something interacts with a database, but we don't want to use a real database for some quick tests. (Please excuse the C#.)

```
[Test]
public void SaveTodoItemToDatabase() {
  var substituteDb = Substitute.For<IDatabase>();
  var todoScreen = new TodoViewModel(substituteDb);

  todoScreen.Item = "Read StackOverflow";
  todoScreen.CurrentUser = "Anna";
  todoScreen.Save();

  substituteDb.Received().SaveTodo("Read StackOverflow", "Anna");
}
```

The idea here is we've separated the `TodoViewModel` from the details of saving to the database. We don't want to worry about configuring a database, or getting a connection string, or having data from previous test runs interfering with future tests runs. Testing with a real database can be very valuable, but in some cases we just want to test a smaller unit of functionality. Mocking is one way of doing this.

For the real app, we'll create a `TodoViewModel` with a real implementation of `IDatabase`, and provided that implementation follows the expected contract of the interface then we can have a reasonable expectation that it will work.

Hope this helps.

---

*Update in response to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383818/nsubstitute-test-against-classes-vb-net/23385437?noredirect=1#comment35826864_23385437)*

The test for `TodoViewModel` assumes the implementation of the `IDatabase` works so we can focus on that class' logic. This means we'll probably want a separate set of tests for implementations of `IDatabase`. Say we have a `SqlServerDb`implementation, then we can have some tests (probably against a real database) that check it does what it promises. In those tests we'll no longer be mocking the database interface, because that's what we're testing.

Another thing we can do is have "contract tests" which we can apply to any `IDatabase` implementation. For example, we could have a test that says for any implementation, saving an item then loading it up again should return the same item. We can then run those tests against all implementations, `SqlDb`, `InMemoryDb`, `FileDb` etc. In this way we can state our assumptions about the dependencies we're mocking, then check that the actual implementations meet our assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, David. I understand the idea of mocking. But what, if the real implementation don't follows the expected contract or rather has code errors in it like the Add-method in the sample above? Do i test those methods without mocks?

Comment: Updated answer to clarify this point. If it's still unclear please let me know.

Comment: If i understand it correct, i mock an interface to isolate a class from its dependencies to a database, filesystem etc. But if the same class has methods, which are independent from any dependencies i don't need a mock to test this methods (in the sample above the Add-Method)?